# Dynamodb table query time not decreasing even if i increase provisioned RCU

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table User whith following attributes-

```
userBirthYear - partition key- number
userDOB - sort key (number -in millisecond)
searchable - attribute (bool)
country - attribute (string)
```

Our query is - find user between an age range where searchable= true and country=xyz
Currently we query for each birthYear calculated using age range and merge result at the end.

We have provisioned RCU 500 and while load testing for some queries response time is not coming less than 1 second even if we increase the RCU to 1000.

Comment: If you are using a filter expression in your query, you should check to see the scanned item count vs the returned item count.

Comment: Yes scanned count is almost 80% of the total count for a wide age range query but my question is how can i reduce query latency, i have tried increasing the RCU to 4 times but query takes the same time. Is there any other approach i can take to reduce query time.

Comment: Are you using a high level client library? If so, there could be multiple calls happening behind the scenes. If the scanned count is much higher than the returned items count and you’re using a higher level library, then you can probably fix the problem by using a more efficient query.

Comment: No we are using low level client interface, using java- com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.QueryRequest. This is the query printed in logs-      {TableName: user,KeyConditions: {dateOfBirth={AttributeValueList: [{N: 313397934680,}, {N: 786610734680,}],ComparisonOperator: BETWEEN}, yearOfBirth={AttributeValueList: [{N: 1991,}],ComparisonOperator: EQ}},FilterExpression: #country = :v_country and #searchable = :searchable,ExpressionAttributeNames: {#searchable=searchable, #country=country},ExpressionAttributeValues: {:v_searchable={BOOL: true}, :v_country={S: India,}}}

Comment: Is it 1 second for each user birth year query, or 1 second for all of them to complete?

Comment: 1 second for all of them to complete.

Comment: How many years are you querying at once?

Comment: around 25 years

Comment: You should take a look at the query latency in dynamodb web console. If each query is an average of 40ms, and you make 25 queries in series, then you have 1 second right there. In order to speed this up, you should use an index that allows you to make fewer queries and/or you should execute the queries in parallel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184786/discussion-between-m-kumar-and-matthew-pope).